# Why were my rebuttals to another user's comments deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

In the comments to my answer on this question:  [Is there a deterministic guide to landing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/90951/is-there-a-deterministic-guide-to-landing), User71659 made several blatantly incorrect assertions.  I countered, but my comments have been deleted with no explanation or similar deletion of this users remarks.

I will admit that my responses were blunt and lacked some grace, but there was nothing offensive in them. I simply responded with some mild and apparent disdain.  The comments of this user were not on topic, seemed agenda driven, were so obviously wrong and lacking in basic reading comprehension that they felt like trolling, that I didn't feel compelled to dignify them further.

I would understand deleting the entire series because the conversation was obviously not productive, but I am personally offended that whoever did this would leave the unrebutted falsehoods in place.

Would you please delete this user's remarks, or explain the benefit of leaving them be with me being denied an opportunity to counter?

Answer (score 7):

While you may feel that your comments were just "blunt and lacked some grace," others may see them as being more harsh.

You felt that the other user was not understand what you were trying to explain in your answer and comments, and communicated that in the following way:

> You whiffed on my point. Read it again... and the count is now 2
> strikes, no balls... Strike three, you are out.

Our [Code of Conduct](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/conduct) on the network considers unacceptable behavior to include "subtle put-downs or unfriendly language." I would consider this a "subtle put-down" in this context and not a friendly way to express that another user isn't understanding you.

You also wrote the following in your comments:

> Please don't garbage up my answer with any more extraneous commentary

> Go away, and take your presumptions and opinions with you.

This also comes across as rude and unfriendly. If a user is making an effort to respectfully engage in a discussion, you shouldn't be telling them to go away. Comments are the appropriate place for some limited discussion regarding posts.

We expect all users to abide by rules in the Code of Conduct:

- If you're here to help others, be patient and welcoming.
- Be clear and constructive when giving feedback, and be open when
  receiving it.
- Be inclusive and respectful.

You're welcome to edit your answer or leave comments to respond to the criticism of others as long as you remain respectful even when disagreeing. If you notice that someone is not meeting the expectations in the Code of Conduct, please flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Ok, yes... a bit more harsh in the glare of daylight, but extra infuriating that one side remained as ymb1 agrees.  And while harsh, I am not inclined to tolerate lightly the actions of trolls who hijack a thread of mine to pontificate, misquote me, and insult my country as well as the OP for being too cheap to rent a turbine with a radio altimeter and autoland capability.  FYI, I have offered my counterpoints, and thanks for clearing space by moving it to discussion.  If there no way to leave the relevant comment(s) in place?

Comment: And while not as overtly harsh as I was, I would submit that this user certainly didn't offer any "clear and constructive" feedback relevant to my answer, and therefore that side of the conversation should have been deleted as well.  Because if it had, we wouldn't still be talking about it here...

Comment: Final remark: "You felt that the other user was not understand(ing) what you were trying to explain..." Bizzare misquotes aside, this was not that.  I am reasonably adept at sensing when someone just doesn't understand me, and despite what you might think, I can be very patient explaining things at the appropriate level to someone who's genuinely confused.  This user, however, seemed intent on using my answer as a springboard for their agenda.

Comment: Consider how it would be received if you went on a DIY hobbiest website dedicated to improving woodworking skills, quilting, etc. and brazenly extolled the superiority of industrial robots in producing the results members painstakingly created for personal pleasure, and further insinuated that anyone not using such a robot was a cheapskate.  That is exactly how this user hijacked my answer, and I didn’t appreciate the distraction.

Comment: P.S.  Did you happen to notice my response to the appropriate critique offered by jsejcksn?!